# Firefox not using Kerberos despite being configured to

Tags: kerberos, firefox

I am deploying Linux/Firefox on a corporate Kerberos network.

I followed [this Kerberos-on-Firefox procedure](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sso-config-firefox.html) but still Firefox does not connect via the company's Kerberos.

I am using Firefox 3.0.18 on RedHat EL Server 5.5

Here is what I did:

- Run `kinit` on the command line to create a Kerberos ticket
- Check with `klist`: the ticket is valid until tomorrow, service principal is `krbtgt/DC.THECOMPANY.COM@DC.THECOMPANY.COM`.
- In Firefox, set `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris` to `.dc.thecompany.com`.
- Load the company's portal page via its full hostname: `http://server37.thecompany.com/alfresco`. *(note: `server37` is actually the machine I am running Firefox on, but that should not be a problem I guess)*

**PROBLEM:** the company's intranet portal still serves me the login/password page. The same portal correctly uses Kerberos on Internet Explorer/Windows 7 machines, same settings, and shows the user's personal page.

The server does not see any Kerberos request coming.
Did I do something wrong?

I enabled `NSPR_LOG_MODULES=negotiateauth:5` as explained [here](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sso-config-firefox.html), but the log file stays empty.

Comment: Note: This question is actually on-topic. "Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity", in particular "desktop infrastructure" is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` should be `.thecompany.com` or `server37.thecompany.com`, not `.dc.thecompany.com`. Your server was not in the list of trusted URI and Firefox never tried to use Negotiate authentication.

For security reasons, I would also enable SSL (HTTPS).

Comment: Actually, I also tried `.thecompany.com` (for both variables), and it does not work...

Comment: Use WireShark or Firebug to see the HTTP headers. Search for the authentication headers. If "Negotiate" is missing this means that the server is not trusted by the browser.